Is the Eb key necessary in this passage for flute?
In this song, it is difficult for me to switch from F to low C. I need to put down my middle and ring fingers while also moving my pinky from the Eb key to the low C key, and then switch my fingers again to get to the A.
It made me wonder, couldn't I just put my pinky on the low C key to start the passage instead?  It doesn't seem to affect the intonation of the F.  In fact, it seems to me like the whole piece could just about be played with pinky on C instead of its usual home on the Eb key.
Is this a thing that real flute players do or am I just a hack?


The passage is eighth notes at what looks to be a relatively slow tempo, there should be no problem sliding from the E-flat to the C key. If you are learning this piece you should definitely be practising the 'correct' fingering.
On the other hand if this an exposed solo you have to play in a concert or for an audition and you want to make absolutely sure the low C 'pops out' then it's no problem to leave your finger on the low C for the first F.
Normally this hack would only be used for fast passages.

As a flutist and instrument maker, I can tell you that there's no problem here.  You can let go of that Eb key any time you want, it makes no difference to the G.
